# financial crisis '08: what is it meant by the banks were saved by the states?

Tags: banking, economic-crisis, financial

Were banks literally saved with tax payers' money? Or is it that states borrowed the banks, consequently, the banks must return this money back at some point? Can someone please give me some references?

Comment: Here is an [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_bjDAZazWU) with Bernanke that might be of interest.